# Excel VBA Number Format Category

Tags: excel, vba, currency

I have an Excel worksheet populated with data and I need to use VBA to format the cells, which isn't an issue in itself - getting the cells to show the correct format.  However I am having difficulty setting the number format category to "Currency", is there a way to set this using VBA.  Currently I see the correct format in the cells but the format category is set to "Custom".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Record a macro while formatting the cells shows you how to do it. Just replace the `Selection` the Macro recorder issues by the range you are dealing with.

Assuming r to be your range:

```
with r
  .NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
end with
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I have tried this via a recorded macro, setting the drop-down to "Currency", however when run through VBA, the drop-down is set as "Custom" .  I have been able to set the drop-down for other number format categories: Text = formatRange.NumberFormat = "@"
Number = formatRange.NumberFormat = "0.00"